# Command Works Through Command Line, but Not When Using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, javac, processbuilder

I'm writing a program that includes a feature where the user can type in Java code into a text box and be able to compile and run it. The error I get is: [image]

The two directories shown at the top are correct, and the command works when I do it manually through command prompt from the same working directory. I'm using Windows 10, and also here's the code:

```
public Process compile() throws IOException {
    save(); //saves changes to source file
    System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("javac", file.getCanonicalPath());
    processBuilder.directory(new File(settingsFile.getJdkPath()));
    System.out.println(processBuilder.directory());
    Process process = processBuilder.start(); //Throws exception
    this.compiledFile = new File(file.getParentFile(), file.getName().replace(".java", ".class"));
    return process;
}
```

File to compile: [image]

Working directory: [image]

Comment: check the file permissions of javac

Comment: @flakes: the error message does not suggest that this is the problem

Comment: @flakes I added some debugging code, and the application does have permission to execute javac. I even went one step further and granted all applications full control of javac (probably a bad idea, but will change it back later).

Comment: java doesn't infer file extensions like windows does, maybe you want 'javac.exe'

Comment: @4dc0 Just tried it, and I still get the same error. The only difference now is that it says "cannot run program javac.exe" instead of "cannot run program javac".

Comment: adding the contents of those directories to the question could help. also, have you tried the fully qualified path to javac?

Comment: @4dc0 I edited the post to include the directory contents. And the method getJdkPath() already returns the absolute file path of the bin folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this code, I was able to compile a Test.java file into a Test.class file on my Desktop.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class App {

    public static Process compile() throws IOException {

        String myFilePath = "C:\\Users\\redacted\\Desktop\\Test.java";
        String javacPath = "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_171\\bin\\javac.exe";

        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(javacPath, myFilePath);

        return processBuilder.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Process process = compile();

    }
}
```

[image: Capture]

Using `String javacPath = "javac.exe";` also worked, but that could be because my JDK bin is on my PATH variable.

There is something wrong with your paths or permissions in the ProcessBuilder constructor call.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was that I still had to specify the path of javac.exe in the command itself even though I had it set as the working directory in ProcessBuilder.